# How to style <li> items inside <ul>?

Tags: css, styles, html-lists

I want to do items style like here

[image: ul child items]

and I'm doing it with UL. Here is the code what I have http://jsfiddle.net/WVLR9/1/

```
ul.gallery_items {
    width: 831px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.gallery_items li {
    width: 260px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 19px;
}
ul.gallery_items li:first-child {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

but I have no idea why the 4th item have bigger margin-left option... it should be in the same place like 1st item but in the second line. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/WVLR9/2/

You put margin-left: 19px on the li's rather than margin-right.

Margin left was causing the 4th row to be a certain margin away from the left border

```
    ul.gallery_items{
    width: 831px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.gallery_items li{
    width: 260px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 19px;

}
ul.gallery_items li:first-child{
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: yup, thats helped me. Silly head thought it should be done with margin-left. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly giving the first item a different left margin:

```
ul.gallery_items li:first-child{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
ul.gallery_items li{
    margin-left: 19px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

4th item has the same margin as other items, you just removed margin from the first item:

```
ul.gallery_items li:first-child{
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

and it looks like something is wrong with 4th element;

1. You could use `margin-right` instead of `margin-left`
2. You could wrap each row with additional `<div class="row">`
3. You could remove `margin-left: 0` form the first element, and give `margin-left: -19px` to the parent element

Answer (score 0):

how about this :)

```
ul.gallery_items li{
  width: 260px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 19px; /* maybe you will need to adjust your margin on the ul element. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.gallery_items{
width: 831px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
list-style: none;
}
ul.gallery_items li{
width: 260px;
height: 200px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
float: left;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-right: 10px;}
```

this should do it.

You've applied a

```
ul.gallery_items li:first-child{
margin-top: 25px;
margin-left: 0px;
```

}

thats why first item didnt have left margin